# Query for orphaned relations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to cleanup orphaned associations in a Rails app which uses OmniAuth. For the sake of simplicity, here's a stripped down scenario.

Given two tables:

```
users:
  password_id: INTEGER
  <more columns>

passwords:
  id: INTEGER NOT NULL
  password_digest: VARCHAR
```

In other words: There's a facultative "user belongs_to password" relation. (There are good reasons why the relation is not the other way around.)

Normally, every user relates to one password. But sometimes a user is deleted and the corresponding password gets orphaned.

Is there an efficient way to find all orphaned passwords (in other words: all passwords which are not related to by any user) with just one SQL query on Postgres?

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: One nitpick: you say there's a good reason to have the relation, but the fact that multiple users belong to the same password means that any data leak has the possibility of leaking a multitude of accounts. This also implies that you're not salting passwords. These are both practices that are frowned upon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of query is called an anti-join.  The simplest method is:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM passwords p
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.password_id = p.id
WHERE u.<primary key field> IS NULL;
```

Another alternative is the `NOT EXISTS` method @Politank-Z gave.  They should have basically identical query plans.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this was possible!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.id FROM PASSWORDS p
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE p.id = u.password_id );
```

...is a straightforward enough solution. You could build it around a `LEFT JOIN` or a `MINUS` if you prefer. You could also prevent the scenario entirely by adding a foreign key from `users` to `passwords`.

Comment: Good solution, however, the anti-join is easier to build with the ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

SELECT *
     FROM passwords
    WHERE I'd NOT IN (SELECT password_id FROM users)

Or

```
SELECT please.*
  FROM passwords please LEFT JOIN
       users u ON p.id=u.password_id
 WHERE u password_id IS NULL
```